# jwt-goにおけるJWTのパースについて教えていただきたいです。

Tags: go, jwt

以下のjwt-goを用いたparse関数について、`token.Method.(*jwt.SigningMethodHMAC);`の動作について教えていただきたいです。

```
func parseToken(tokenString string) (*jwt.Token, error) {  
    token, err := jwt.Parse(tokenString, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {  
    if _, ok := token.Method.(*jwt.SigningMethodHMAC); !ok {  
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("there was an error")  
        }  
        return []byte(os.Getenv("API_SECRET")), nil  
    })  
    if err != nil {  
        return nil, err  
    }  
      
    return token, nil  
}
```